# Issue with cell editor, Command button action fires even after internal validation error

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, tablecelleditor

For a column having a cell editor which has decimal as value, if i tried to enter string characters it showing validation error but it also invokes the action related to that button. 
the save button code I have is

`<p:commandButton id="saveBtn"  value="#{msgs['button.save']}" accesskey="#{msgs['accesskey.save']}"   escape="false"   process="configRulePanel"
onclick="var d=PF('wigVardataTable'), c=d.jq.find('td:has(.ui-cell-editor-input:visible)'); if(c.length)d.saveCell(c);  " update="myErrorMessages" action="#{ConfigBean.requestSave}" />`
and the Input text in the cellEdit is

`<p:inputText id="itemId" value="#{configRule.configItemValue}" validatorMessage="validation failed" validator="cellValidator" >                                         <f:convertNumber  minFractionDigits="0"  maxFractionDigits="5"/>                    </p:inputText>`

Iam using primefaces 5.3, 
How to stop save action when there is error in the page , Any suggestions??

Comment: Do you also have outputText in the cellEdit?

Comment: yes definetly :)

Comment: Ok, check what will happen if you remove outputText part from cellEdit :-) .